# duda con formulario en HTML5 y PHP

Tags: php, html, html5

tengo el siguiente formulario que creo con PHP:

```
echo '<form name="frmCalificar" method="post" action="calificar.php">';
            echo '<br>Calificacion:<input type="number" name="txtCalificacion" required/><br>';
            echo '<p>Observacion:</p><textarea name="txtObs" rows="5" cols="21" ></textarea><br>';  
            echo '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="btnRechazar" value="Rechazar">';
            echo '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="btnAceptar" value="Aceptar">';
            echo '</form>';
```

que se ve  muestra de la siguiente manera:
[image: Vista de formulario]

como se puede observar en el código el espacio de calificación es requerido a la hora de enviar el formulario, pero solo quiero que sea requerido al presionar en el botón aceptar, al rechazarlo no se requiere ese campo, ¿hay alguna manera de hacer esto?
que a la hora de presionar el botón aceptar si el campo de calificación esta en blanco me lo pida, pero al presionar en rechazar se pueda enviar el formulario sin estar obligado a poner algo en calificación.

nota: para los 2 botones se debe guardar el campo de comentario, pero sin ser obligatorio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tu caso concreto te puede servir el atributo **formnovalidate** para los botones *submit* que lo que hace es que si pulsas en ese *submit* no valida el formulario, pero claro para formularios mas complejos donde el rechazar si pueda requerir de alguna validación no te servirá pues anula la validación de todo el formulario, en esos casos, vas a necesitas si o si hacer tu propia validación con *javascript*.

```
echo '<input type="submit" formnovalidate class="btn btn-danger" name="btnRechazar" value="Rechazar">';
```

Mira a ver si te sirve y me comentas, yo he hecho una pequeña prueba en local y parecía ir bien.

Comment: muchísimas gracias amigo como lo mencionas esto funciona para mi caso perfectamente se te agradece